# Вывод первого элемента, если все элементы равной длины

Tags: c++, vector

Я обращался по поводу задачи из Практикума с выводом из вектора самой длинной строки и ее индекса. Мне нужно доработать ее так, чтобы все элементы вектора одинаковой длины, выводился первый элемент.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
    int longest_index = 0;
    int current_index = 0;
    int siz = some_vector[longest_index].size();
    for (string el : some_vector){
        int siz1 = el.size();
        if (siz1 > siz) {
            longest_index = current_index;
        }
        current_index = current_index+1;
        if (siz1 = siz) {
            current_index = 0;
            longest_index = current_index;
        }
    }
    cout << "Longest string " << "\"" << some_vector[longest_index] << "\"" << " at index " << longest_index << endl;
```

С моим кодом программа не проходит проверку, не могу понять, как правильно сделать вывод первого элемента, если все элементы равной длины.

P.S. Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, пока только учусь...

Comment: Во-первых, достаточно заппоминать _первый_ индекс для самой длинной строки.  Во-вторых, в строке `if (siz1 = siz)` -- классическая опечатка.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно запоминать длину самого большого элемента вектора, кроме того, следует предусмотреть ситуацию, когда вектор пустой:

```cpp
int longest_index = -1;
int current_index = 0;
int max_size = -1;
for (string el : some_vector) {
    int curr_size = el.size();
    if (current_index == 0 || curr_size > max_size) {
        longest_index = current_index;
        max_size = curr_size;
    }
    current_index++;
}
if (longest_index != -1) {
    cout << "Longest string " << "\"" << some_vector[longest_index] << "\"" 
<< " at index " << longest_index << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Longest string not found in the empty vector" << endl;
}
```